# Restore GtkWindow at location where it was hidden?

Tags: gtk3

I am hiding a preference window with gtk_widget_hide, but when I unhide it using gtk_widget_show, it shows up at the location where it was created, i.e. on the center of the screen, instead of where I left it. Looks like I'm overlooking a triviality: any help is appreciated.

Comment: This might be the way your window manager is set up. If my answer didn't help, please post your WM for reference.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with window manager compiz.

Comment: A bit OT but why keep the window hidden instead of creating it every time the users need it? A preference window doesn't seem an recurrent action that deserves this kind of behavior.  Other than that, @theGtknerd answer it's a very practical solution. Ĩ've used it in the past but even then, the window would be destroyed, recreated and moved to the last position before being shown. Good luck.

Comment: The preference window has subpanels, which may or may not be visible, and I would like to maintain this state. Also, I would like to use the same principle for another window, with a tree view which may be partially collapsed/expanded. The easiest way to maintain the state of the internals of the window is to stick to that same window.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need [gtk_window_get_position](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-get-position) before hiding.

And then [gtk_window_move](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-move) after showing.